# Android ExpandableList - Image Loader - Simple Adapter

Tags: android, android-imageview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, android-loader

i need very much our help.

I need create a expandableListView and put inside more images loaded to url.

Now i have this:

i take the text to file xml but i dunno how show in image my image dinamic.

This is code:

```
Main.java

public class Main extends ExpandableListActivity {


    static final String KEY_DISCOUNTED_PRICE = "discounted_price";
    static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
    static final String KEY_DISCOUNT = "discount";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL_SELLER = "seller_image_url";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "image_url";
    static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    static final String KEY_TITLE_OFFERTA = "title_offerta";    
    String contenuto_nodo;
    ArrayList <String> array_contenuto_nodo =new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();




    static final String shades[][] = {
// Shades of grey
      {
        "lightgrey","#D3D3D3",
        "dimgray","#696969",
        "sgi gray 92","#EAEAEA"
      },
// Shades of blue
      {
        "dodgerblue 2","#1C86EE",
        "steelblue 2","#5CACEE",
        "powderblue","#B0E0E6"
      },
// Shades of yellow
      {
        "yellow 1","#FFFF00",
        "gold 1","#FFD700",
        "darkgoldenrod 1"," #FFB90F"
      },
// Shades of red
      {
        "indianred 1","#FF6A6A",
        "firebrick 1","#FF3030",
        "maroon","#800000"
      }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        TaskHomePageLista task = new TaskHomePageLista();
        task.execute();
        try {Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // ImageLoader class instance

        SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
            new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                createGroupList(),  // groupData describes the first-level entries
                R.layout.list_row,  // Layout for the first-level entries
                new String[] { KEY_PRICE, KEY_DISCOUNT, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_DISCOUNTED_PRICE, KEY_TITLE_OFFERTA},  // Key in the groupData maps to display
                new int[] { R.id.price, R.id.discount, R.id.description, R.id.discounted_price, R.id.title_offerta},        // Data under "colorName" key goes into this TextView

                createChildList(),  // childData describes second-level entries
                R.layout.child_row, // Layout for second-level entries
                new String[] { "shadeName", "rgb" },    // Keys in childData maps to display
                new int[] { R.id.childname, R.id.rgb }
            );


        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );


        // Imageview to show


    }

/**
  * Creates the group list out of the colors[] array according to
  * the structure required by SimpleExpandableListAdapter. The resulting
  * List contains Maps. Each Map contains one entry with key "colorName" and
  * value of an entry in the colors[] array.
  */
    private List createGroupList() {


      return (List)songsList;
    }

/**
  * Creates the child list out of the shades[] array according to the
  * structure required by SimpleExpandableListAdapter. The resulting List
  * contains one list for each group. Each such second-level group contains
  * Maps. Each such Map contains two keys: "shadeName" is the name of the
  * shade and "rgb" is the RGB value for the shade.
  */
  private List createChildList() {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < shades.length ; ++i ) {
// Second-level lists
      ArrayList secList = new ArrayList();
      for( int n = 0 ; n < shades[i].length ; n += 2 ) {
        HashMap child = new HashMap();
        child.put( "shadeName", shades[i][n] );
        child.put( "rgb", shades[i][n+1] );
        secList.add( child );
      }
      result.add( secList );
    }
    return result;
  }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    class TaskHomePageLista extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {




        protected void onPreExecute(Void... params) {

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {

                // passo i parametri di mail e password alle variabili 


                //setto la pagina
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.miosito.HomePageXml.aspx");
                 // aggiungo alla lista le variabili

                // chiamo la pagina che mi da una risposta.

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);

                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

                DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                        .newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = builder.parse(in);
                String[] nomi = new String[6];
                nomi[0] = "price";
                nomi[1] = "image_url";
                nomi[2] = "seller_image_url";
                nomi[3] = "discount";
                nomi[4] = "discounted_price";
                nomi[5] = "description";




                if (doc != null) {
                    // dichiaro n3 per la lunghezza dell'item principale di quello che devo selezionare. 

                    NodeList n3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("promo");
                        NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("home");
                    for (int i = 0; i < n3.getLength(); i++) {

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        for( int num=0; num < nomi.length; num++){
                        n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName(nomi[num]);

                            if (n2.getLength() > 0) {
                            Node node = n2.item(i);

                            contenuto_nodo = node.getTextContent();
                            array_contenuto_nodo.add(contenuto_nodo+"///");


                                if(nomi[num].equals("price")){
                                map.put(KEY_PRICE, "Valore" + Html.fromHtml("<BR>" + node.getTextContent() + " €"));

                                }

                                if(nomi[num].equals("image_url")){
                                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, node.getTextContent());
                                }

//                              if(nomi[num].equals("seller_image_url")){
//                              map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL_SELLER, node.getTextContent());
//                              }

                                if(nomi[num].equals("discount")){
                                map.put(KEY_DISCOUNT, "Sconto" + Html.fromHtml("<BR>" + node.getTextContent() + " %"));
                                }

                                if(nomi[num].equals("discounted_price")){
                                map.put(KEY_DISCOUNTED_PRICE, node.getTextContent()+ " €");
                                }
                                if(nomi[num].equals("description")){
                                map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, node.getTextContent());
                                }

                                System.out.println("sto elaborando");

                                }

                            n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("home");
                            }   
                        n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("promo");
                        if (n2.getLength() > 0) {
                            Node node = n2.item(i);
                               node = node.getFirstChild();
                             map.put(KEY_TITLE_OFFERTA, node.getTextContent());
                        }


                        songsList.add(map);


                    }


                System.out.println("array_titolo_categoria_home is: "  + array_contenuto_nodo ); 

//              controllo_login_tempo = "finito";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {

        }

        }
    }
```

In KEY_THUMB_URL after AsynkTask i have the url of image. I need show at harth with image loader. But i dunno how implement image loader in the SimpleExpandableListAdapter. Please help me is very important!

I think i can use this:

```
int loader = R.drawable.loader;

// Imageview to show
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

// Image url
String image_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";

// ImageLoader class instance
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

// whenever you want to load an image from url
// call DisplayImage function
// url - image url to load
// loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
// image - ImageView 
imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
```

but i dunno where i must put this code... Please help!

Look this image for screen
http://www.magicfly.it/app/screen.jpg

Comment: me too struggle presence.... Got any o/p?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution.

"This class can be used by external clients of SimpleAdapter to bind values to views. You should use this class to bind values to views that are not directly supported by SimpleAdapter or to change the way binding occurs for views supported by SimpleAdapter."

So ImageView. The expected bind value is a resource id or a string and setViewImage(ImageView, int) or setViewImage(ImageView, String) is invoked.

public class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder {

```
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,

    String textRepresentation) {

        if ((view instanceof ImageView) & (data instanceof Bitmap)) {

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;

            Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data;

            iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and

```
   HashMap<String, Object> man = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(aURL.openStream());
                    modles.put(samURL,bitmap);
```

then

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder()); //its below declaration of adapter
```

source : [click here](http://www.anddev.org/display_image_in_list_urgent_required-t6537.html)